# sed command to print lines between two patterns

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to print lines between two patterns through sed command. But I want to include the line containing Pattern1 in the result and exclude the Pattern2.
For ex:

```
/PAT1/
line 1
line 2
line 3
/PAT2/
```

The desired output is :

```
/PAT1/
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I have tried this :

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT2/{d};p}' Input_File
```

But it is excluding both the patterns.

Comment: It works as desired for me.

Comment: Maybe you wrote `/PAT/` inside the `{}`?

Comment: What version of `sed`? It works with GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Comment: works as desired for me on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`...

Comment: May also be written `sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/!d;/pattern2/d' file`

Comment: Is there an issue where the second pattern would match the first?  e.g. from `Keyword:` to `<anything>:` , where I'd like the lines from and including `Keyword: ...` up to but excluding the next keyword line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with awk: `awk '/patt1/{flag=1}/patt2/{flag=0}flag' input_file`

If input_file is:

```
111 
222 
333 
444 
555
```

`awk '/222/{flag=1}/444/{flag=0}flag' input_file`

gives:

```
222
333
```